# Converting $9e^{(3+i\pi/6)}$ into cartesian form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

For a question of $$9e^{(3+i\pi/6)}$$ I thought the answer would be $$9((\cos(3+\pi/6)+i \sin(3+\pi/6))$$ which would give out a "a + bi" form of $9\cos(3+\pi/6)+9 \sin(3+\pi/6)i$, but I quiz showed me an error. Is that not the correct answer? Why not, since my other similar answers were fine? Thanks if you could point out my mistake. *Hope that the formatting works

Comment: Check Euler's identity closely.

Answer (score 2):

1. $9((\cos(3+\pi/6)+i \sin(3+\pi/6))=9^{i(3+ \pi/6)} \ne 9e^{3+i\pi/6}.$
2. $9e^{3+i\pi/6}= 9e^3 e^{i \pi/6}.$
3. $ \cos( \pi /6)=\sqrt{3}/2$ and $ \sin ( \pi/6)=1/2.$